# WAMP and PHPmyAdmin

Tags: wamp

I am running a WAMP server on a virtual cloud hosting I have.

My phpMyAdmin is saving my database in the following directory

```
  C:\wamp\bin
```

As this is a cloud hosting I have limited space on my c:\ and running low. I have mounted additional drives but now need to use those drives as my storage drives. How can I have phpMyAdmin save the info on one of the mounted drives?

I have tried naming the mounted drive c:\wamp but it is not starting up the services if I copy all the files over to there.

All I need is the database to be saved on larger mounted drive. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I am relatively new to WAMP

Using Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Quite certainly `phpMyAdmin` does _not_ save your databases to that folder! `phpMyAdmin` is a _database client_, which means it uses a _database server_ (`MySQL`) to store (use) databases in. So most likely your _real_ question is how to reconfigure and migrate the `MySQL` database servers storage location to another location in the file system?

Comment: So if I change my.ini file datadir to the folder I want and copy all the current data there this should work if I understand you correctly

Comment: Sure. You should move, not copy the data and you have to stop and restart the MySQL server before/after you move the data.

Comment: **Make sure you have a backup** Before doing **ANYTHING**